# HTML tag properties

Tags: html, tags

I see on some tags using "unusual" properties like the data-id and data-gps-track properties on `<a>` tag.Also aria-hidden property on `h3` tag and so on...So my question is are these "official" tags or everyone can write a property on his own?

Comment: No, everybody can not write properties on their own, [data-](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) is HTML5 attribute.

Comment: Read this too : http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute--webdesign-9642

Comment: Thanks for the replies but also i found some aria-* properties.What about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute mentioned in the question are allowed according to [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) Last Call Working Draft, which is the current W3C working group document on HTML5. Whether you call it “official” is your choice. The document itself says: “ This is a draft document and may be updated, replaced or obsoleted by other documents at any time. It is inappropriate to cite this document as other than work in progress.” However, many people regard the W3C HTML5 document as “standard”.

According to HTML5, authors can use `data-*` attributes for their own purposes. No meaning is assigned to them in the specification, and no meaning will be assigned to them in specifications.  So they are a “standard” way of using custom attributes.

The `aria-*` attributes are not defined in HTML5, but HTML5 normatively refers to ARIA specifications for their definitions and permits using them. They have defined meanings, and their set is fixed (though it may be changed by future changes to ARIA specifications).

Answer (score 1):

It's new* in HTML5. You can create your own data-* attributes. There is some handy usage when combining with Javascript.

Here is a pretty good run down.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes